# CURL keep throwing "Invalid body format"

Tags: json, windows, curl, cmd

so I have this body of a CURL:

```
-d '{
  "documentType": "SQMProjectFact",
  "status": "published",
  "selectAttributes": [
"Supplier"
],
  "filterExpressions": [
    {
      "name": "createdDateFrom",
      "field": "TimeCreated",
      "op": ">=",
      "defaultValue": "2018-08-05T01:01:59Z
"    },
    {
      "name": "createdDateTo",
      "field": "TimeCreated",
      "op": "<=",
      "defaultValue": "2018-08-15T01:01:59Z"
    }
  ]
}'
```

When I run it on postman, it works tottaly fine, but when I try to do it on CMD, it keeps throwing me "Invalid body format". 
I research and try chagning ' for ", and " for \", and a lot of conmbinations of that, erasing the spaces (just to see if it that solved it), but it stills throwing me that error.

Just for info, these are the headers:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer xXxXXXxx-xxXx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"  
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "accept: application/json"
-H "apiKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Thanks for those who will reply!

Comment: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` runs commands line by line which means a line ending not escaped with `^` is interpreted as end of the command line to execute. So you need to escape each line ending in JSON data with `^` or you write the JSON data in a single line. And additionally `'` has no special meaning for `cmd.exe`. It is a character like `a` or `9`. An argument string with spaces and operators like `&<>|` must be enclosed in `"` to be interpreted as literal characters of __one__ argument string which also means that `"` inside a double quoted argument string is often not possible.

Comment: I suggest to write the JSON data into a JSON file and run *Curl* with specifying the JSON data file instead of trying to specify the JSON data directly on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I will try specifying the JSON file and keep you updated.

Comment: @Mofi It worked!, Thank you!